# Verifying a (convolution) solution for ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having trouble in verifying that $f\star \phi$, $\phi = \frac{1}{2} e^{-|x|}$ is a solution for $u -u''=f$. Please help me.

Comment: Compute $-\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \phi$ in distributional sense. That's almost all you have to do.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I'm not suppose to use distribution theory, do you know another approach?

Comment: Do you know what a "Dirac $\delta$" is?

Comment: Hint: Take the Fourier transform of the differential equation, then invert, using the Fourier convolution property.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first review what a derivative does to a Fourier transform.  I write the FT of a function $u(x)$ as

$$\hat{u}(k) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \: u(x) e^{i k x}$$

The inverse FT is then

$$u(x) =  \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dk \: \hat{u}(k) e^{-i k x}$$

Now, let's consider the FT of the derivative of $u$, $u'(x)$:

$$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \: u'(x) e^{i k x} &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d(u'(x))  e^{i k x}\\ &= \underbrace{[(e^{i k x}u(x)]_{-\infty}^{\infty}}_{\text{this is zero}} - i k \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \: u(x) e^{i k x} \\ &= -i k \hat{u}(k) \end{align}$$

Each derivative is equivalent to multiplying the FT by $-i k$.  Now we apply this knowledge to the original equation:

$$-u''+u=f(x)$$

Take the FT of both sides.  Note that the 2nd derivative is equivalent to multiplying by $(-i k)^2$:

$$(1+k^2) \hat{u}(k) = \hat{f}(k) \implies \hat{u}(k) = \frac{\hat{f}(k)}{1+k^2}$$

Let $\bar{\phi}(k) = \frac{1}{1+k^2}$. One may show that $\phi(x) = \pi e^{-|x|}$.  The solution $u(x)$ may be written as

$$\begin{align}u(x) &= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dk \: \hat{u}(k) e^{-i k x}\\ &=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dk \: \frac{\hat{f}(k)}{1+k^2} e^{-i k x}\\ &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx' \: f(x') \phi(x-x') \end{align}$$

by the convolution theorem.

Comment: I'm sorry I think I didn't write clearly, one suppose to plug $f\star \phi$ in the original DE and verify that works...